# How to validate route params using symfony 6 constraints attributes?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

I have a route in controller with some parameters, I want to validate them by using custom constraint class as an attribute over the parameter, is it possible to do?

I found something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/article/{id}", name="article_show")
 * @ParamConverter("id", constraints={
 *     @Assert\NotNull,
 *     @Assert\Type(type="digit")
 * })
 */
public function show($id)
{
  // ...
}
```

but that does not work in symfony 6 there is no option constraints in `ParamConverter` attribute. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#parameters-validation